# How to use findViewById for an autocomplete textview inside a fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

Here is my code so far. I should mention this is my first time attempting to use Android studio. Any books you all could recommend would be great as well:

```
public class master_profile extends Fragment {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    public master_profile() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master_profile, container, false);
    autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.auto_complete);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,words)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class master_profile extends Fragment {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    public master_profile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master_profile, container, false);
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        String[] words = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.auto_complete);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Comment: The new error is cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words); i will edit my answer